# How to enter break in Sitecore RichText editor?

Tags: sitecore, rich-text-editor

When I hit enter on a line in sitecore richtexteditor I get a new paragraph instead of a line break. I can manually add it by editing html but how can I add line break in the Design mode itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hold down the Shift key and press Enter (Shift+Enter)

Comment: In addition to this (I don't have a Sitecore web config handy right now) there should also be a setting that will define what to use for line breaks in the rich text editor.

Answer (score 4):

The setting in web.config to change the tag inserted on enter key in RTEs is:

```xml
<!--  HTML EDITOR LINE BREAK
      Specifies the tag that the HTML editor inserts on Enter. Values can be
      "br", "div" and "p".
-->
<setting name="HtmlEditor.LineBreak" value="br"/>
```